# how to give id dynamically to an element in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Hi i am doing an application in phonegap,in that application i need to show list of the users in the listview contains profile pic,name,number and online status .

```
for (var i = 0; i < roster_items.length; i++) {
    var jid_contact=roster_items[i].getAttribute('jid');
    var name_contact=roster_items[i].getAttribute('name');
    ///  Add all the contacts to  Array
        $('#contacts-listview').append(
                                       '<a href="#" onclick="user_contactsClicked('+ i + ');">' +
                                       '</br>'+
                                       '<div id="contact_img">'+
                                       '<img id="splash" src="images/contact_default_pic.png"  />'+
                                       '<ul id="menu">'+'<li id="contact">'+name_contact+'</li>'+
                                       '<li id="status">'+jid_contact+'</li>'+'</ul>'+
                                       '<div class="pull-right"><div><img id=i class="status_img" src="images/user_online.png"  /></div>'+
                                       '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><ol id="date">'+
                                       '<li>date</li>'+
                                       '<li>time</li>'+
                                       '</ol></div></div>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                       '</br>'+
                                       '</a>'
                    );
        }
```

and i will call a function   for changing the online status for a particular user and changes the image

```
changeOnlineStatus_contact : function(elementPos) {
    alert(elementPos);
    if(elementPos>=0) {
        //Get current table
        document.getElementById(i).src = "images/user_offline.png";
    }
}
```

for this i want to give if for the img element dynamically. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: this is bad practice, you should use a template engine like handlebars or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the id isn't getting set on the image is because you've got:

`"…<img id=i class=…"` which means that every image has the id of "i"

If you changed this to:

`"…<img id=\""+i+"\" class=…"` then it would use the value of `i` as the id attribute

---

If you have more complex bindings to the UI, I'd recommend looking at something like http://knockoutjs.com/ - this way you would update the underlying model, and the html would automatically be updated to represent it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have changed as you mentioned,  id=\""+i+"\" and            document.getElementById(i).src ="images/user_online.png";  for changing the image ,but it is notworking .